# Spring Boot initializing fields to null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this controller that finds one or more resources, depending if `id` is null or not.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/teste")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> find(Optional<ZonaIdDTO> id) {
    if (id.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            this.zonaMapper.toZonaRetrievalDTO(this.zonaService.findById(id.get())),
            HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        this.zonaService
            .findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(this.zonaMapper::toZonaRetrievalDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()),
        HttpStatus.OK
    );
}
```

The problem is that the condition `id.isPresent()` is always evaluated to `false`, even when I don't pass an `id` to the controller. In that case, the `id` object fields are initialized to `null`, but I want the object itself to be `null`. What can I do?

EDIT: To be extremely clear, I want to know why the parameter `id` isn't `null` when I make a request without any parameter. Even using `ZonaIdDTO` instead of `Optional<ZonaIdDTO>` doesn't work. Instead, all the fields of `id` are set to `null`.

For example:

```
// `id` should be null here
GET localhost:8080/teste

// `id` shouldn't be null here
GET localhost:8080/teste?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Comment: is your problem the fact that `ZonaIdDTO` is always coming in as an empty Optional? or that you cannot use it in your logic as `null`?

Comment: also, what do you want this id to be? query parameter? request body? I believe something is missing here

Comment: @TrandafirEmanuel `id` is meant to be a `RequestParam`.

Comment: @TrandafirEmanuel the problem is that when I send an `GET` request without any params, I expect `id` parameter to be set to `null`, but instead, all its fields are set to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the comment the id should be a request parameter and it should be optional (can be omitted). Try this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam(required = false) Optional<ZonaIdDTO> id)
```

The annotation @RequestParam is needed for Spring to handle the id as a request parameter. And to distinguish it from the other kind of method parameter which is a path variable.

Check this: [baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

And the attribute 'required' is needed to distinguish between mandatory and optional parameter. Please also note that the naming is important. If your request parameter is abc then your method parameter must be abc (at least by default, you can override it using attribute 'name').

Comment: Why is the `@RequestParam(required = false)` annotation needed? Shouldn't Spring set a empty optional if there is no `id`? I really want to understand.

Comment: I edited my original question to be more clear.

Comment: And I edited my original answer to be more clear as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The optional in java can never be null. It has to be always non-null and if there is no data the `id.isPresent()` will be false.

If you don't need the object `id` to be null, you would require to keep the function signature as

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> find(ZonaIdDTO id)
```

Comment: This didn't work, `id` still isn't `null`, only its fields are.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice. You should seperate your services and you should not have an Optional at this step. You can use Optional extracting data from your database because you're not sure to have what you expect but with your client, you should respect some contract and just return an exception 4xx if the client doesn't respect the contract (Http 400 bad request for example).

your contract should be like

> GET /Example : extract all Example Objects

> GET /Example/{id} : extract One Example object with the id defined by {id}

```
@GetMapping(value = "/teste/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<ZonaRetrievalDTO> getById(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.zonaMapper.toZonaRetrievalDTO(this.zonaService.findById(id)),
            HttpStatus.OK
        );
}
@GetMapping(value = "/teste")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<Set<ZonaRetrievalDTO>> getAll() {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(
    this.zonaService
        .findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(this.zonaMapper::toZonaRetrievalDTO)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()),
    HttpStatus.OK
  );
}
@PostMapping(value = "/teste")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<ZonaRetrievalDTO> getByCompositeKey(@RequestBody ZonaIdDTO zonaId) throws StructuralEntityException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.zonaMapper.toZonaRetrievalDTO(this.zonaService.findByZonaId(zonaId)),
            HttpStatus.OK
        );
}
```

try to avoid the <?> to be readable in your development. you should not work with different object for the same web service

Comment: I was doing that way, but my resource is identified by a composite key (query params), so my url path for them would end up being the same and Spring doesn't allow that. That's why I unified them in one controller.

Comment: it should be really rare to extract a composite key. Either you're in this specific case, either you did a mistake in your conception because your work for example with (latitude, longitude) instead of an autogenerated id. If you specifically need to localize, then you keep the previous Web Services  `GET : /Zone`,  `GET /Zone/{id}`
and add `GET /Zone/localize/{lat}/{lng}` or simply `POST /Zone/localize`. I will update with an example for the post

Comment: The context of zone in my application isn't the same you're talking about, so that solution of yours don't really fit for my case. But I understand what do you mean and appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the parameter as optional parameter.

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestBody(required ="false") ZonaIdDTO id) {

if(id != null) {
...
} else {
...
}

}
```

And yea, it is bad practise to implement logic in controller level. Just write a service class and call the service class method in this controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has a design issue and the answers above give you the way to do it. You are trying to force a behavior in your application that is not compatible with the way REST Architecture works.

1. First your parameters should simply be a DTO to help you parse your object into `json`
2. You can delete the `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)` on your method, because you already return the status OK
3. By default a boolean always return **false**
4. Just use a `ZonaIdDTO` as a parameter

Comment: But when I use `ZonaIdDTO` as a parameter, it is never `null`. For example, let's say I called that endpoint without passing an `id` object (`localhost:8080/teste`). Then, I expect `id` to be `null`, but that's not happening. Instead, a `ZonaIdDTO` object is created and its fields are set to `null`. Do you understand?

Comment: Do you have a `400` status when calling `localhost:8080/teste`?

Comment: No, it returns a 200 status. The `id` is not empty, so `id.isPresent()` is evaluated to `true`.